# Where can I buy egg and chips near Glasgow Central?

Tags: uk, food-and-drink, glasgow

Arriving in Glasgow Central station on the sleeper, I'd like to have breakfast and, for preference, egg and chips or failing that a vegetarian cooked breakfast of some kind that would include eggs. There doesn't seem to be anything suitable on the station concourse, what about nearby?

To be clear, somewhere that opens no later than 8:00am (ideally 7:30am), is needed. Suggestions for 10:00am opening are too late.

Comment: There is a Burger King where you can have a veg burger, tried myself. You would just need to get out of the station. There are loads of eateries on either side of the roads when you get out of the station. I think there is awesome cake/chocolate(not sure) shop near the exit gates in the station, towards platform 14/15.

Comment: There was an interesting looking answer below that seems to have been deleted - anyone know why?

Comment: @FrancisDavey It has been deleted by the “owner” (i.e. the person who wrote it).

Comment: Thanks @Relaxed. A pity because it had what looked like a useful suggestion in it. Is there an edit log that might explain the removal?

Comment: @FrancisDavey No, moderators have to provide a justification when they delete something but the person who answered can delete their own post without explanation. The suggestion was a place called [Cafe Wander](http://www.cafewander.com/).

Comment: @pnuts - there may be "no shortage" but I will be very hungry and rather desperate at 7:30 in the morning and will almost certainly not be able to wander Glasgow finding somewhere. "Look around" or similar advice doesn't work for me. A link to a list of eateries which may or may not be nearby or may or may not be open at that time etc isn't much help either. Attempts to find the answer myself using google, streetview etc were unsuccessful. Hence asking the question.

Comment: Glasgow is a great city to wander - compact and full of independent surprises - but it's also an "open late, stay open late" kind of place, so it's a good idea to be pre-armed at 7:30am. If I remember right, when I was sampling  Wetherspoon's breakfasts, it was because nowhere else was open yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two early-opening Wetherspoon's pubs right by Glasgow Central. Wetherspoon's do well priced, reliable vegetarian breakfasts. I've been in one for a super-early veggie fry-up and it was quiet, spacious and relaxing on a morning, with very comfy sofas. Can't remember which one, is probably true of both.

- [The Sir John Moore, which opens at 7:30am](https://www.google.co.uk/maps/place/The+Sir+John+Moore/@55.8591283,-4.2563456,879m)
- [The Crystal Palace, which opens at 8am](https://www.google.co.uk/maps/place/The+Crystal+Palace,+36+Jamaica+St,+Glasgow,+Glasgow+City+G1+4QD/@55.8574912,-4.2573578,17z/d)

And there's a [10am opening chippie](https://www.google.co.uk/maps/place/The+Blue+Lagoon/@55.858603,-4.258036,17z) right by the exit that (I think) will do you pickled eggs alongside an authentic [Glasgow salad](https://www.facebook.com/pages/The-Glasgow-Salad/131626806848548). Lots of chippies near the station do chips & cheese.

But I'd consider not just stumbling to somewhere nearby. Glasgow has been voted one of the UK's best cities for vegetarians and vegans and has [many great independent places](http://glasgow.stv.tv/articles/270311-flying-duck-big-vegan-fete-and-other-vegan-friendly-glasgow-restaurants/). Off the top of my head, Mono, Tchai Ovna, Stereo and The Arches are all very well loved (but I think they open later). There are many more.

Comment: The Wetherspoon's pub link is a link to google maps for Crystal Palace - I'm not sure I understand.

Comment: That's the pub's name - if it's taking you to the wrong place, maybe  google maps is using your location as its starting point... I'll fix it... okay seems to work now

Comment: Ah, that may be it. Searching for "Isle of Skye" on google maps sometimes gives me Charles Kennedy's office in London which is not what I want.

Answer (score 3):

For completeness I will say where we did eventually go (the information about the Sir John Moore came too late). We went to the [Wee Guy's Cafe](http://guysrestaurant.blogspot.co.uk/2013/05/welcome-to-wee-guys.html) at 51 Cochrane Street.

It opens at 7:00am and is at most 10 minutes walk from Central Station, even with quite a bit of luggage. It is therefore very suitable for someone arriving on the sleeper hungry. It serves a Full Scottish breakfast and was flexible enough to make me what I wanted.